# replace metamask with web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, metamask

Is it possible to replace metamask with a web3.js + geth / parity solution in a dapp? Or do you need the infura service?
What is the difference between using metamask and web3.js + node? Are there any advantages or disadvantages?